# How to create complex schema in FastAPI?

Tags: python, post, get, rest, fastapi

I am trying Fast API very first time today and stuck on this problem. I want to get the data in the following JSON format:

```
{
    "list":{
        "clubs": [
            {
                "club_members": [
                    {
                        "name": "john",
                        "age": 30
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "bob",
                        "age": 34
                    }
                ],
                "club_name":"Ivy",
                "club_address":"main st"
            },

            {
                "club_members": [
                    {
                        "name": "anna",
                        "age": 22
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "kim",
                        "age": 24
                    }
                ],
                "club_name":"Fann",
                "club_address":"Bradford st"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have a working app that displays the `get` method.

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from pydantic import BaseModel

app=FastAPI()

db = []

class Information(BaseModel):
    name:str
    address: str



@app.get('/info')
def get_info():
    return db





@app.post('/cities')
def create_info(city:Information):
    db.append(city.dict())
    return db[-1]
```

at my localhost, I can see the following output.

```
[{"name":"bob","address":"22 main st"}]
```

how should I add my fields in the Information class so I can get the response I mentioned in the very beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Code like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

app=FastAPI()
db = []


class Member(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


class Club(BaseModel):
    name: str
    address: str
    members: List[Member]


class City(BaseModel):
    clubs: List[Club]


@app.get('/info')
def get_info():
    return db


@app.post('/cities')
def create_info(city: City):
    db.append(city.dict())
    return db[-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    from pathlib import Path

    os.system(f'uvicorn {Path(__file__).stem}:app --reload')
```

Test with httpie:

```
$ http :8000/cities clubs:='[{"name":"a","address":"b","members":[{"name":"c","age":1}]}]'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 71
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 07 Apr 2021 02:27:28 GMT
server: uvicorn

{
    "clubs": [
        {
            "address": "b",
            "members": [
                {
                    "age": 1,
                    "name": "c"
                }
            ],
            "name": "a"
        }
    ]
}

$ http :8000/info
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 73
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 07 Apr 2021 02:29:00 GMT
server: uvicorn

[
    {
        "clubs": [
            {
                "address": "b",
                "members": [
                    {
                        "age": 1,
                        "name": "c"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "a"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```